# Uploading files securely with php - OOP

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote code to upload multiple(2) files.

1.Check if this is image: mime/extension/getimagesize.
2.Remove execute file permissions from the file(chmod).

Is this script secure? What can go wrong?

***Class photograph***

```
class Photograph extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $table_name = "photographs";
    protected static $db_columns = ['id', 'filename', 'filename2', 'type', 'type2', 'size', 'size2', 'caption'];

    public $id;
    public $filename;
    public $filename2;
    public $type;
    public $type2;
    public $size;
    public $size2;
    public $caption;

    private $temp_path;

    //protected $upload_dir="../images";
    protected $upload_dir = PUBLIC_PATH . '/images';

    protected $max_file_size = 1048576; // 1 MB expressed in bytes

    public $errors = array();

    // Define allowed filetypes to check against during validations
    protected $allowed_mime_types = ['image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'];

    protected $allowed_extensions = ['png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg'];

    protected $upload_errors = array(
        0 => 'There is no error, the file uploaded with success.',
        1 => 'Larger than upload_max_filesize.',
        2 => 'Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.',
        3 => 'Partially uploaded.',
        4 => 'No file.',
        6 => 'No temporary folder.',
        7 => 'Failed to write file to disk.',
        8 => 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload.',
    );

    protected function sanitize_file_name($string) {
    // Remove characters that could alter file path.
    // I disallowed spaces because they cause other headaches.
    // "." is allowed (e.g. "photo.jpg") but ".." is not.
    $string = preg_replace("/([^A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]|[\.]{2})/", "", $string);
    // basename() ensures a file name and not a path
    $string = basename($string);
    return $string;
    }

    protected $check_is_image = true;

    private function size_as_kb() {
        if ($this->size < 1024) {
            return "{$this->size} bytes";
        } elseif ($this->size < 1048576) {
            $size_kb = round($this->size/1024);
            return "{$size_kb} KB";
        } else {
            $size_mb = round($this->size/1048576, 1);
            return "{$size_mb} MB";
        }
    }

    private function size_as_kb_2() {
        if ($this->size2 < 1024) {
            return "{$this->size2} bytes";
        } elseif ($this->size2 < 1048576) {
            $size_kb = round($this->size2/1024);
            return "{$size_kb} KB";
        } else {
            $size_mb = round($this->size2/1048576, 1);
            return "{$size_mb} MB";
        }
    }

    // Returns the file permissions in octal format.
    private function file_permissions($file) {
        // fileperms returns a numeric value
        $numeric_perms = fileperms($file);
        // but we are used to seeing the octal value
        $octal_perms = sprintf('%o', $numeric_perms);
        return substr($octal_perms, -4);
    }


/* ==================================================================================
                        public function attach_file($file)
================================================================================== */

    public function attach_file($file) {

          $this->temp_path   = $file['tmp_name']['0'];
          $this->filename    = $this->sanitize_file_name($file['name']['0']);
          $this->type        = $file['type']['0'];
          $this->size        = $file['size']['0'];

          $this->temp_path2  = $file['tmp_name']['1'];
          $this->filename2   = $this->sanitize_file_name($file['name']['1']);
          $this->type2       = $file['type']['1'];
          $this->size2       = $file['size']['1'];

    }
/* ==================================================================================
                        public function upload file 1
================================================================================== */

public function upload_file() {

    $filename_extension = pathinfo($this->filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($this->size > $this->max_file_size) {
        // PHP already first checks php.ini upload_max_filesize, and 
        // then form MAX_FILE_SIZE if sent.
        // But MAX_FILE_SIZE can be spoofed; check it again yourself.
        echo "Error: Your product image 1 is too big. The file has: {$this->size_as_kb()}.<br />";
        return false;
    }

    if(!is_uploaded_file($this->temp_path)) {
        echo "Fatal error: Possible alien attack!<br />";
        return false;
    }

    // check if this is image: mime/extension/getimagesize - return false.
    if(!in_array($this->type, $this->allowed_mime_types)) {
        echo "Error: Not an allowed mime type.<br />";  
    }

    if(!in_array($filename_extension, $this->allowed_extensions)){
        echo "Error: Your product image 1 file extension is not supported.<br />";

    }

    if($this->check_is_image && (getimagesize($this->temp_path) === false)) {
        // getimagesize() returns image size details, but more importantly,
        // returns false if the file is not actually an image file.
        // You obviously would only run this check if expecting an image.
        echo "Error: Not a valid image file.<br />";
        return false;
    }
    // ends - check image

    // Can't save without filename and temp location
    if(empty($this->filename) || empty($this->temp_path) ) {
        $this->errors[] = "The file location was not available.";
        return false;
    }
    $target_path = $this->upload_dir . '/' . $this->filename;

    // Make sure a file doesn't already exist in the target location
    if(file_exists($target_path)) {
        $this->errors[] = "The file {$this->filename} already exists.";
        return false;
    }
    // Attempt to move the file 
    if(move_uploaded_file($this->temp_path, $target_path)) {
        echo "First file name is '{$this->filename}'.<br />";
        echo "First file moved to: {$target_path}<br />" ;
        echo "Uploaded file size was {$this->size_as_kb()}.<br />";
        echo "<br />";
        // Success  

        // remove execute file permissions from the file
        if(chmod($target_path, 0644)) {
            echo "Execute permissions removed from file: {$this->filename}.<br />";
            $file_permissions = $this->file_permissions( $target_path );
            echo "File permissions are now '{$file_permissions}'.<br />";
            }
            else {
                echo "Error: Execute permissions could not be removed.<br />";
            }
            echo "<br />";

    } else {
        // File was not moved.
    $this->errors[] = "The file upload failed, possibly due to incorrect permissions on the upload folder.";
        return false;
    }       

}

/* ==================================================================================
                        public function upload file 2
================================================================================== */

public function upload_file2() {

    // Can save first without second filename and temp location
    if(!empty($this->filename2) || !empty($this->temp_path2)) { 

        $filename_extension2 = pathinfo($this->filename2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if($this->size2 > $this->max_file_size) {
            // PHP already first checks php.ini upload_max_filesize, and 
            // then form MAX_FILE_SIZE if sent.
            // But MAX_FILE_SIZE can be spoofed; check it again yourself.
            echo "Error: Your product image 2 is too big. The file has: {$this->size_as_kb_2()}.<br />";
            return false;
        }

        if(!is_uploaded_file($this->temp_path2)) {
            echo "Fatal error: Possible alien attack!<br />";
            return false;
        }

        // check if this is image: mime/extension/getimagesize - return false.
        if(!in_array($this->type2, $this->allowed_mime_types)) {
            echo "Error: Not an allowed mime type.<br />";  
        }

        if(!in_array($filename_extension2, $this->allowed_extensions)){
            echo "Error: Your product image 2 file extension is not supported.<br />";

        }

        if($this->check_is_image && (getimagesize($this->temp_path2) === false)) {
            // getimagesize() returns image size details, but more importantly,
            // returns false if the file is not actually an image file.
            // You obviously would only run this check if expecting an image.
            echo "Error: Not a valid image file.<br />";
            return false;
        }
        // ends - check image


        $target_path2 = $this->upload_dir . '/' . $this->filename2;

        // Make sure a file doesn't already exist in the target location
        if(file_exists($target_path2)) {
            $this->errors[] = "The file {$this->filename2} already exists.";
            return false;
        }
        // Attempt to move the file 
        if(move_uploaded_file($this->temp_path2, $target_path2)) {
            echo "Second file name is '{$this->filename2}'.<br />";
            echo "Second file moved to: '{$target_path2}'<br />" ;
            echo "Uploaded file size was {$this->size_as_kb_2()}.<br />";                   
            echo "<br />";
            // Success
            // remove execute file permissions from the file
            if(chmod($target_path, 0644)) {
                echo "Execute permissions removed from file: {$this->filename2}.<br />";
                $file_permissions2 = $this->file_permissions( $target_path2 );
                echo "File permissions are now '{$file_permissions2}'.<br />";
                }
                else {
                    echo "Error: Execute permissions could not be removed.<br />";
                }
                echo "<br />";


        } else {
            // File was not moved.
            $this->errors[] = "The file upload failed, possibly due to incorrect permissions on the upload folder.";
            return false;
        }
    }

}

/* ==================================================================================
                                public function save()
================================================================================== */

    public function save() {
        // A new record won't have an id yet.
    if(isset($this->id)) {

    $this->upload_file();

    $this->upload_file2();

    if($this->update_photo()) {
        // We are done with temp_path, the file isn't there anymore
        unset($this->temp_path, $this->temp_path2);
        return true;
            }
    } else {

    // Can't save if there are pre-existing errors
    if(!empty($this->errors)) { return false; }

    $this->upload_file();

    $this->upload_file2();  

    // Save a corresponding entry to the database
    //if($this->create3()) { - dziala
    if($this->create()) {
                // We are done with temp_path, the file isn't there anymore
                unset($this->temp_path, $this->temp_path2);
                return true;
}
}
}
```

***photo_upload.php***

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $photo = new Photograph();
        $photo->caption = $_POST['caption'];
        $photo->attach_file($_FILES['file_upload']);
        $photo->attach_file($_FILES['file_upload']);
        if($photo->save() ) {
            // Success
        } else {
            // Failure   
        }   
    }

<form action="photo_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

        <p><input name="file_upload[]" type="file" id="file_upload[]" value=""></p>

        <p><input name="file_upload[]" type="file" id="file_upload[]" value=""></p>

        <p>Caption: <input type="text" name="caption" value="" /></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
```

Comment: You want to know whether your script is secure. Secure against what? What is your [threat model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model)?

Comment: I want to know if this is a good practice. Chmod, filename_extension and so on.

Comment: That has nothing to do with whether it's secure or not. What are your expectations for this code?

Comment: e.g that the hacked photo, script, file with 777 mode will not get to the server.

Comment: You want to protect against hacked photos?

Comment: A lot of your code seems to be missing since I see a lot of empty if-else statements. Can you clarify your concerns and what's up with the empty blocks? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Manty I don't have enough of a critique to merit a review, but `/([^A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]|[\.]{2})/` is more simply written as `/[^\w.-]|\.{2}/` and `unset()` can receive one or more parameters in a single call.

Comment: `unset($this->test1, $this->test2, $this->test3); ` - Yes - you're right

Comment: ` /[^\w.-]|\.{2}/ `- I have to test and check documentation.

Comment: Empty blocks?  Everything works - I mean `if error return false`, I checked this 10 times - sanitize file, chmod, max file, is image and so on...

Comment: " Hacked photos" - `getimagesize()` returns image size details, but more importantly, returns false if the file is not actually. You obviously would only run this check if expecting an image.

Comment: A file could be of several types at once. If a file is of the image type it doesn't mean it couldn't be of php type at the same time.

Comment: "several types at once"? Example please.

Comment: Why do you repeat a lot of code, with the same functionality, to upload the second photo? This is not [DRY](https://www.thinktocode.com/2017/11/20/dont-repeat-dry). What will you do if you have to add a third photo? It is also obvious that the `save()` method is far too long.

Comment: Good advice, thank you, I don't know how to code this, but I will think about it tomorrow.